# Texture ASButtonNode, how to set the image in the right of text

Tags: ios, textures

[image]

like this, the distance of title and image can be customized

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ASOverlayLayoutSpec`.

like this.

```
------------ASOverlayLayoutSpec------------ 
|  -ASInsetLayoutSpec  ASInsetLayoutSpec  | 
|  |  ASButtonNode  |  |  ASImageNode  |  | 
|  ------------------  -----------------  | 
-------------------------------------------
```

reference

http://texturegroup.org/docs/layout2-layoutspec-types.html#asoverlaylayoutspec
http://texturegroup.org/docs/automatic-layout-examples-2.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[buttonNode setImageAlignment: ASButtonNodeImageAlignmentEnd];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**2020: Swift Solution**

`buttonNode.imageAlignment = .end`